# Reading data - WebSQL

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I want to "read" from a webSQL client-side database, but alert don't throw out any data. Here is the code:

```
    var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'text', 2*1024*1024, callback());
    var interval;

    function callback(){
        interval = setInterval(callback1.bind(this), 1000);
    }

    function callback1(){
        if(db != 'undefined'){
            clearInterval(interval);
            db.transaction(function(tx){
                tx.executeSql('create table if not exists jj(id unique, text)');
                tx.executeSql('insert into jj values(1, "kata")');
                //It's here! <----------------------------------------------
                tx.executeSql('select * from jj', [], function(tx, results){ 
                    alert(results.rows.item(0).text);
                });
            });
        } else {
            alert('error');
        }
    }
```

Where have I made mistakes?

Comment: Just as a sidenote if you're starting out: WebSQL has been deprecated in favor of IndexedDB: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_Database_API

Comment: (official webSQL documentation features this nice huge banner warning you: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ )

Comment: @amenthes Thank you, I haven't been aware of it. I'm that kind of human who doesn't  read big banners unfortunelly

Comment: I toyed around with it a little bit, but I couldn't figure out what the problem was, I'm sorry.